# ENV variable to get the standard host name for the local machine - Apache

Tags: apache

Is there a way to set ServerAlias to the actual machine host name via a variable e.g.

lets say machine is named: MacBook-Pro.local, is Apache keeping it under some variable which could be set as:

`ServerAlias HOSTNAME`

tried `HOSTNAME`, `HOST_NAME`, nothing seems to be working?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about how to set hostname in apache/Tomcat.  There is a Host configuration option in conf/server.xml

```
    <Host name="www.mycompany.com" ...>
     ...
    <Alias>mycompany.com</Alias>
     ...
    </Host>
```

Please see more in documentation [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html) 
Hope this helps you or at least sets you in the right direction

Comment: No I'm not, its about Apache Web Server - httpd - apache2 - I am asking if there is an ENV variable which can be used for ServerAlias, e.g. something like $HOSTNAME which you can use for log name pattern